# Limit of BSM Gamma as stock price goes to 0

Tags: black-scholes

BSM gives the following formula for option gamma
$$
\Gamma = \frac{e^{-qT-\frac{d_1^2}{2}}}{S\sigma\sqrt{2\pi T}}
$$
where
$$
d_1=\frac{\ln\frac{S}{K}+(r-q+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)T}{\sigma\sqrt{T}}
$$
Then, to calculate its limit as $S\rightarrow 0^+$, the key is to calculate
$$
\lim_{S\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{e^{-\frac{d_1^2}{2}}}{S}
$$
Since $d_1\rightarrow-\infty$ as $S\rightarrow 0^+$, I'm thinking of using L'Hopital's rule. However, everytime one takes a partial derivatve of $e^{-\frac{d_1^2}{2}}$ with respect to $S$, there will be another $S^{-1}$ showing up since
$$
\frac{\partial d_1}{\partial S}=\frac{1}{S\sigma\sqrt{T}}
$$
Hence, does anyone know how to calculate the limit (I know it should be 0)?
A similar problem is how to calculate following limit?
$$
\lim_{S\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{e^{-\frac{d_1^2}{2}}}{\frac{1}{S}}
$$

Comment: It is clear that there are constants $a$ and $b$ that do not depend on $S$ such that
$$
\gamma(S):=\frac{d_1^2+2\ln S}{2}=\frac{(\ln S+a)^2+b}{2}\,.
$$
Therefore this term goes to $+\infty$ when $S\to 0$ or $S\to+\infty\,.$ Since $\Gamma$ equals $e^{-\gamma(S)}$ up to a constant it follows that
$\Gamma\to 0$ when $S\to 0$ or $S\to+\infty\,.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about expressing $S$ in terms of $d_1$, then plugging this formula into the denominator of your limit, then take limit as $d_1$ tends to negative infinity ( instead of taking limit on S).